# Difference on montgomery curve equation between EFD and RFC7748

Tags: elliptic-curves, x25519, rfc7748

There is a subtle difference between the 2 implementations for a Montgomery curve defined from the 2 following links

https://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-montgom-xz.html

```
      A = X2+Z2
      AA = A^2
      B = X2-Z2
      BB = B^2
      E = AA-BB
      C = X3+Z3
      D = X3-Z3
      DA = D*A
      CB = C*B
      X5 = (DA+CB)^2
      Z5 = X1*(DA-CB)^2
      X4 = AA*BB
      Z4 = E*(BB+a24*E)
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7748

```
       A = x_2 + z_2
       AA = A^2
       B = x_2 - z_2
       BB = B^2
       E = AA - BB
       C = x_3 + z_3
       D = x_3 - z_3
       DA = D * A
       CB = C * B
       x_3 = (DA + CB)^2
       z_3 = x_1 * (DA - CB)^2
       x_2 = AA * BB
       z_2 = E * (AA + a24 * E)
```

This AA / BB change on the last line does affect the result of a point multiplication with same input parameters.

Is there a reason for that difference ?

Comment: It looks to be a typo in RFC. When BB is used (as in EFD and original P.L. Montgomery paper), the test vectors can be reproduced. Submitted a review comment to RFC. Errare humanum est. How many existing implementations will fail to inter-operate ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug: it arises from different choice of sign in the definition of `a24 := (a ± 2)/4`; the RFC uses - while the EFD uses +.

RFC, following the [Curve25519 paper](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#curve25519):

> The constant a24 is (486662 - 2) / 4 = 121665 for curve25519/X25519 and (156326 - 2) / 4 = 39081 for curve448/X448.

EFD, following [Montgomery's paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2007888) ([paywall-free](https://sci-hub.tw/https://www.jstor.org/stable/2007888)):

> Assumptions: 4*a24=a+2.

This apparent discrepancy was [raised by Paul Lambert](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/cfrg/RYtOJDmPfZ7Mu-p_jKiGjr2T4eQ) on the CFRG mailing list during discussion on the draft.  It doesn't really matter which one you choose, as long as you're consistent about it!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't spot the little difference on a24 definition between the RFC and the EFD.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a typo; it is a difference in how the Montgomery doubling formula was derived between the [original paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866113-7/S0025-5718-1987-0866113-7.pdf) and the [curve25519 paper](https://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf). Both are correct.

To double a point on a Montgomery curve
$$
y^2 = x^3 + Ax^2 + x\,,
$$
one has the identity relating the doubled point $(x_3, \cdot)$ and the source point $(x_1, \cdot)$:
$$
x_3 4x_1(x_1^2 + Ax_1 + 1) = (x_1^2 - 1)^2\,.
$$
The doubled point $x_3$ can thus be computed as the fraction 
$$
 \frac{(x_1^2 - 1)^2}{4x_1(x_1^2 + Ax_1 + 1)}\,.
$$
But to minimize the operation number, and obtain several common subexpressions, we can write $(x_1^2 - 1)^2$ as $(x_1+1)^2(x_1-1)^2$, $4x_1$ as $(x_1 + 1)^2 - (x_1 - 1)^2$, and $x_1^2 + Ax_1 + 1$ as either $(x_1-1)^2 + ((A+2)/4)4x_1$ or $(x_1+1)^2 + ((A-2)/4)4x_1$. It is this latter somewhat arbitrary choice that results in there being two almost identical Montgomery doubling formulas.